# How can I use the username from the user as a path

Tags: php, url-routing

I want to to take the username from every user and make it the path for their profile. so the path should be localhost:8080/user but I can not get it to work. although I can make it to work with id.

Thank you for help in advance! :)

routes.json

```
":username": {
    "controller": "User",
    "method": "getProfileByUsername",
    "params": {
      "username": "string"
    }
  }
```

UserController.php

```
public function getProfileByUsername($username)
    {
        $userModel = new UserModel();

        try {
            $user = $userModel->getProfileByUsername($username);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $properties = ['errorMessage' => 'User not found!'];
            return $this->render('views/error.php', $properties);
        }

        $properties = ['user' => $user];
        return $this->render('views/profile.php', $properties);
    }
```

UserModel.php

```
public function getProfileByUsername($username)
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username';
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute(['username' => $username]);

        $users = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, self::CLASSNAME);
        if (empty($users)) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }


        return $users[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your web server to redirect such paths to something like `getuser.php?user=(user)` - how to do it depends on your web server.

On Apache 2, this can be done using .htaccess. I suggest to have users in some subfolder like `/user/`, as it will make redirecting much easier.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ ./getuser.php?user=$1
```